# Does there exist a Danmaku Yuugi: Flowers revised edition, especially in English?

Tags: danmaku-yuugi-flowers

I recently had the unique joy of learning that an RPG I'd wished for did, in fact, already exist. (I immediately made a few more wishes, just in case.) The game in question is "Danmaku Yuugi: Flowers," and it's a TRPG based on the "Touhou" series of bullet hell shooter computer games.

I've yet to actually run it, but I like the cut of its jib: The attack patterns and tension mechanics are reasonably clever adaptions of the danmaku attacks and sprite graze mechanics of the computer games, and having skills that represent a character's personality traits and mannerisms rather than her capabilities and areas of competence seems like it'd allow for some creative events and solutions to problems.

However, I happened to read a rumour that the game's developers had received feedback from players after the initial release, and were planning to release a revised version with a number of clarifications and improvements. That sounds rather good, to be honest; The version of the game I have in my hands could do with a few minor tweaks to its organisation and rules content, and getting my hands on the revised edition might save me from having to make house rules to compensate.

Alas, I've been unable to find this revised version anywhere... And it soon occurred to me that perhaps the developers' good intentions never bore fruit. **Does the revised-and-clarified version of Danmaku Yuugi: Flowers exist?** And if it does, **has it been translated into English?**

Comment: Upvoted:  It amuses me to see a mention of Danmaku Yuugi: Flowers on here, as my brother was one of the people to translate it in the first place (starting on low-quality scans).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the "revised edition" of the game does exist, under the name *Touhou Danmaku Yūgi flowers second blooming* (東方弾幕遊戯 flowers second blooming). I have never actually read the new material myself and so can't comment on what was changed. It does not appear to have been translated into English (certainly not in an "official" capacity).

---

Another Touhou TTRPG you might search for is 千幻抄 ～幻想郷TRPG～ (Sengenshō ~Gensōkyō TRPG~). The rules are all on [a Japanese wiki](http://wikiwiki.jp/sengensyou/). It is extremely crunchy IMO, and you will probably need a good understanding of Japanese to work with it. A few friends and I started translating the thing for personal use but it was a huge effort that died out after a while...